# Listing expired plone contents only in specific contexts (folders or collections)

Tags: plone

I've to list, in specific folders or collections, objects expired also to anonymous users.
You know, portal_catalog returns only brains not expired. It's a useful behavior but not in this case...

To force the Catalog to return also expired contents, we've to pass a specific parameter: show_inactive.

Browsing the folder_listing (&family) code I noticed that it's possible to pass, via request, optionals parameters (contentFilter) to the query/getFolderContents. It's a nice feature to customize the query avoiding the creation of very similar listing templates.

I suppose it's necessary to create a marker interface to mark context (folders or collection) where I want to list also expired contents. For ex. IListExpired.

I imagine to ways:

1) **to make a subscriber** that intercepts before_traverse and , in the handler, a test to verify if the context implements the IListExpired. In positive case I made a

```
request.set('folderListing', {'show_inactive':True})
```

2) **to make a viewlet** for the IListExpired that in the call set

```
request.set('folderListing', {'show_inactive':True})
```

What's the best way? I suppose the first one could be an unnecessary overhead.

Vito

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, these are two separate thing: `folderListing` uses [a method available to all CMF-based Folderish content types](http://svn.zope.org/Products.CMFCore/trunk/Products/CMFCore/PortalFolder.py?view=markup); `show_inactive` is an option of the Plone catalog, so you're not going to make it work as you're planning.

I think you should override these views and rewrite the listing using a catalog call.

you better use a browser layer for you package to do so or, a marker interface as you're planning.